# Vertical Scroll Bar goes blank after I insert a page

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm working with a large 165 page catalog with lots of photos and tables. File size is 450MB
I tried to insert a page (number 7) into the document. As soon as the page was inserted, the vertical scroll bar went blank and I can no longer scroll up and down in the document. Pg Up and Pg Down still works

Comment: Have you done any basic troubleshooting? such as ..... Quit and relaunch InDesign.

Comment: Yes. I spent quite a bit of time trying to find what happened. After opening backup copies and replicating the problem in the backups I decided it's probably not a software issue, but more likely a large-file issue.

Comment: It's probably *not* the file itself. It's the application or operating system (window server maybe). Have you quit and relaunched the *application*? Rebooted the computer? Tried resetting INDD preferences. Sorry but general software troubleshooting is off topic here. 450mb  is large for an INDD file but not *that* large. 7 pages though at 450MB??? what must you be doing? I've created 400pg INDD files that are nowhere near 100mb, let alone 450.

Comment: Yes to all your suggestions. The file and app are on the local drive on a Windows 10 PC built for graphic design

Comment: Scott, it's a 165 page document and I'm having the problem when I insert a new page at page 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It is a file issue** and I have experienced this myself when working with random templates received from clients, either designed in older ID versions or having an improvised setup, or resaved so many times the file itself becomes too complicated for ID to handle.

Then these bugs show up when adding or removing pages, sticking them into spreads, or even worse, deleting/moving objects on pages. ID will literally zoom in to a random place outside a random page and will get stuck there.

Since this is a "165 page catalog with lots of photos and tables", I am positive you've just got one of those tangled, multi-version, multi-edited, lots of people worked on it, template.

Unfortunatelly if you're looking at this scenario, there is no quick fix.

Things you can try:

1. resave the file. literally make a copy via `Save as`. ID will clean up the back-end of a source file, removing some of the junk artwork floating around between artboards, and you may also notice a dramatic size reduction in the file size. If you do this, I am 100% sure the file size will get reduced to 250-300mb in the saved copy (unless you have many images embedded directly, which again would be a sign of a crappy template)
2. export to IDML, open the IDML, resave to INDD and try that. Be advised this option is risky and some formatting could get affected going this route.

Comment: Thanks, Lucian! That fixed my file. Saving as IDML took awhile. When I tried to open the IDML it froze while loading a certain image. I removed the image, saved a new IDML, and opened that successfully. From there I saved as an INDD to replace my original file. I added a page with no problem!